SharePoint list/library buttons disappear when zooming browser
I'm encountering a strange issue in SharePoint lists/document libraries. When I zoom in or out in the browser, certain toolbar buttons, like the "New" button, completely disappear. This doesn’t always happen immediately, but rather randomly. Sometimes you have to zoom in and out several times before the buttons disappear, while other times the effect is immediate. Upon inspecting the elements, I noticed that the button gets a display:none style applied to it.
This doesn't seem to be related to the responsive design, as I would expect the buttons to be grouped or resized, not completely hidden. Also, if I zoom out, there’s no reason for the buttons to be grouped, right? Has anyone else experienced this issue or found a solution?
I'm using SharePoint SE (on premise) and it happens across different browsers. Any suggestions or workarounds would be appreciated!


Sometimes, clearing the browser's cache and cookies can resolve display issues.

We have tried, but it makes no difference. All users are experiencing this issue.
